# ASP.NET Core Web API - The name 'jsonString' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API. I have this code:

ViewModel (Dto):

```
public class MandateDto
{
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? MandateId { get; set; }
}
public class TransactionDto
{
    public string? RawData { get; set; }
}
```

EntityMapper:

```
public class EntityMapper
{
    public Mandate FromMandateDtoToMandate(MandateDto mandate)
    {
        Mandate mandate = new Mandate()
        {
            DueDate = mandate.DueDate,
            StartDate = mandate.StartDate,
            EndDate = mandate.EndDate
        };
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(mandate);
        return mandate;
    }

    public TransactionLog FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog(TransactionDto mandate)
    {
        return new TransactionLog
        {
            RawData = jsonString,
        };
    }
}
```

MandateService:

```
    public async Task<Mandate> Post(MandateDto mandate)
    {
        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var mandate = mapper.FromMandateDtoToMandate(mandate);
        var transaction = mapper.FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog(mandate);

        try
        {
            await _unitOfWork.MandateRepository.Insert(mandate);
            await _unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Insert(transaction);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        return mandate;
        return transaction;
    }
```

As shown in **EntityMapper**, I want to transfer **jsonString** from **FromMandateDtoToMandate** into **FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog** as in:

> RawData = jsonString

I got this error:

> Error CS0103  The name 'jsonString' does not exist in the current context

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog` method has no parameters/variables called `jsonString`, so that's why it doesn't compile.

Comment: Your jsonString-variable is declared inside another method, it's not available where you are trying to access it. You should read about variable scope.

Comment: Move `JsonSerializer.Serialize(mandate)` into `FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog`; you're not using `jsonString` in `FromMandateDtoToMandate` anyway.

Comment: @MartinCostello - What do I do?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog and FromMandateDtoToMandate have different models. jsonString is generated from all the attributes in Mandate model done in FromMandateDtoToMandate.

Comment: @Olugbenga In that case, please update your question because they both take `MandateDto` at the moment.

Comment: What about this -> `mapper.FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog(mandate)`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - Sincerely I'm stuck. How do I do that?

Comment: It's not clear where `TransactionDto` is coming from. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - Yes, it's my code.  TransactionDto is just a ViewModel for TransactionLog which has the attribute RawData

Answer (score 1):

you have to add this line with `jsonString`  otherwise the variable doesn't exist in this scope

```
public TransactionLog FromMandateDtoToTransactionLog(MandateDto mandate)
{
    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(mandate); //add this line!
    return new TransactionLog
    {
        RawData = jsonString,
    };
}
```